# como realizar mas de un registro

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy trabajando con *Android Studio* una `app` en la que se llevan registros para la creación de tarjetas, necesito que para que los registros no se hagan uno por uno puse una sección para colocar la cantidad de registros que se requieran, pero al momento de probar si funciona solo realiza un registro a que se deberá el problema?

**LO QUE HE HECHO**

- La cantidad de tarjetas se extraen de lo que se coloque en el `EditText` llamado `et_Tarjetas`
- Para la función `Private void validarFormulario()` lo convertí a tipo `int`

```
String cantidadTarjetasString = et_Tarjetas.getText().toString().trim();

int cantidadTarjetas Integer.parseInt(cantidadTarjetasString);
```

Esto para validar que el campo esté lleno para luego pasar el valor de `cantidadTarjetas` a la función `private void guardarTarjeta(int cantidadTarjetas);`

**AQUÍ ESTA EL CÓDIGO**

```
public class TarjetasFormularioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PERMISO_ALMACENAMIENTO = 1000;
    Spinner sp_modelos, sp_statusFabricacion, sp_subStatusFabricacion;
    Button btn_cancelar, btn_crear;
    EditText et_nombre, et_Tarjetas;
    TextView tv_numSerie, tv_fechaRegistro;
    MultiAutoCompleteTextView et_comentarios;
    final GeneraNumSerie ticket = new GeneraNumSerie();
    
    
    
    //Vinculamos la parte visual y sus variables
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tarjetas_formulario);
        setTitle("Nueva Tarjeta");

        sp_modelos = findViewById(R.id.spinnerModelosFormulario);
        sp_statusFabricacion = findViewById(R.id.spinnerSFabricacionFormulario);
        sp_subStatusFabricacion = findViewById(R.id.spinnerSSFabricacionFormulario);
        et_nombre = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonNameFormulario);
        tv_numSerie = findViewById((R.id.NoSerie));
        et_comentarios = findViewById(R.id.multiAutoCompleteTextViewFormulario);
        et_Tarjetas = findViewById(R.id.NumeroTarjetas);

        //cargamos el array de los modelos de tarjetas
        ModeloTarjetaController modeloTarjetaController = new ModeloTarjetaController();
        List<ModeloTarjeta> listaModelos = modeloTarjetaController.listarModelos();

        ArrayAdapter adapterModelos = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_row, listaModelos);
        sp_modelos.setAdapter(adapterModelos);

        List<String> modabreviado = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ModeloTarjeta mt: listaModelos) {
            modabreviado.add(mt.getModeloAbreviado());
        }

        //Cargamos todos los spinners de los status y substatus
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterS = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.StatusFabricacion, R.layout.spinner_row);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterVacio = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.SubStatusFabricacionVacio, R.layout.spinner_row);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterEnsamble = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.SubStatusEnsamble, R.layout.spinner_row);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterHorneado = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.SubStatusFabricacionHorneado, R.layout.spinner_row);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterRefuerzoPuerto = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.SubStatusFabricacionRefuerzoPuerto, R.layout.spinner_row);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterDisplay = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.SubStatusFabricacionDisplay, R.layout.spinner_row);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterPines = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.SubStatusFabricacionColocacionDePines, R.layout.spinner_row);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterLimpieza = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.SubStatusFabricacionLimpieza, R.layout.spinner_row);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterVibracion = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.SubStatusFabricacionPruebasDeVibracion, R.layout.spinner_row);

        //Cargamos los estados y subestados del modelo Alfatek
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterAlfatek = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.EstadoAlfatek, R.layout.spinner_row);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterSubestadoRevisionSoldaduraSMD = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.SubestadoRevisionSoldaduraSMD, R.layout.spinner_row);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterSubestadoSoldaduraPuenteBluetooth = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.SubestadoSoldaduraPuenteBluetooth, R.layout.spinner_row);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterSubestadoSolderPot = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.SubestadoSolderPot, R.layout.spinner_row);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterSubestadoRevisionSoldaduraTHT = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.SubestadoRevisionSoldaduraTHT, R.layout.spinner_row);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterSubestadoSoldaduraSMDBL = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.SubestadoSoldaduraSMDBL, R.layout.spinner_row);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterSubestadoPruebasFuncionales = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.SubestadoPruebasFuncionales, R.layout.spinner_row);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterSubestadoRevisionFinal = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.SubestadoRevisionFinal, R.layout.spinner_row);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterSubestadoEmpaquetado = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.SubestadoEmpaquetado, R.layout.spinner_row);


        //Al seleccionar un modelo verifica en la base de datos el siguiente número de serie a asignar
        sp_modelos.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                ModeloTarjeta modeloTarjeta = (ModeloTarjeta) sp_modelos.getSelectedItem();
                Integer idModelo = modeloTarjeta.getId();

                if(modeloTarjeta.getId() == 16){
                    sp_statusFabricacion.setAdapter(adapterAlfatek);
                    sp_statusFabricacion.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
                        //cada que se seleccione un status se cambia el spiner a el sub status seleccionado
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            sp_subStatusFabricacion.setEnabled(true);
                            switch(position) {
                                case 0: //selecmodelo

                                case 1: //Serigrafieado
                                    sp_subStatusFabricacion.setAdapter(adapterVacio);
                                    break;

                                case 2: //Empastado
                                    sp_subStatusFabricacion.setAdapter(adapterVacio);
                                    break;

                                case 3: //Ensamble
                                    sp_subStatusFabricacion.setAdapter(adapterVacio);
                                    break;

                                case 4: //Horneado
                                    sp_subStatusFabricacion.setAdapter(adapterVacio);
                                    break;

                                case 5: //Revisión de soldadura SMD
                                    sp_subStatusFabricacion.setAdapter(adapterSubestadoRevisionSoldaduraSMD);
                                    break;

                                case 6: //Soldadura en puente bluetooth
                                    sp_subStatusFabricacion.setAdapter(adapterSubestadoSoldaduraPuenteBluetooth);
                                    break;

                                case 7: //Ensamble THT
                                    sp_subStatusFabricacion.setAdapter(adapterVacio);
                                    break;

                                case 8: //Solder Pot
                                    sp_subStatusFabricacion.setAdapter(adapterSubestadoSolderPot);
                                    break;

                                case 9: //Revisión soldadura THT
                                    sp_subStatusFabricacion.setAdapter(adapterSubestadoRevisionSoldaduraTHT);
                                    break;

                                case 10: //Soldadura SMD Bottom Layer
                                    sp_subStatusFabricacion.setAdapter(adapterSubestadoSoldaduraSMDBL);
                                    break;

                                case 11: //Pruebas funcionales
                                    sp_subStatusFabricacion.setAdapter(adapterSubestadoPruebasFuncionales);
                                    break;

                                case 12: //Limpieza
                                    sp_subStatusFabricacion.setAdapter(adapterVacio);
                                    break;

                                case 13: //Revisión final
                                    sp_subStatusFabricacion.setAdapter(adapterSubestadoRevisionFinal);
                                    break;

                                case 14: //Empaquetado
                                    sp_subStatusFabricacion.setAdapter(adapterSubestadoEmpaquetado);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    sp_statusFabricacion.setAdapter(adapterS);
                    sp_statusFabricacion.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
                        //cada que se seleccione un status se cambia el spiner a el sub status seleccionado
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            sp_subStatusFabricacion.setEnabled(true);
                            switch(position) {
                                case 0: //selecmodelo

                                case 8://entregada
                                    sp_subStatusFabricacion.setAdapter(adapterVacio);
                                    sp_subStatusFabricacion.setEnabled(false);
                                    break;

                                case 1:
                                    sp_subStatusFabricacion.setAdapter(adapterEnsamble);
                                    break;

                                case 2: //horneado
                                    sp_subStatusFabricacion.setAdapter(adapterHorneado);
                                    break;

                                case 3://refuerzo de puerto
                                    sp_subStatusFabricacion.setAdapter(adapterRefuerzoPuerto);
                                    break;

                                case 4://display
                                    sp_subStatusFabricacion.setAdapter(adapterDisplay);
                                    break;

                                case 5://colocacion de pines
                                    sp_subStatusFabricacion.setAdapter(adapterPines);
                                    break;

                                case 6://Limpieza
                                    sp_subStatusFabricacion.setAdapter(adapterLimpieza);
                                    break;

                                case 7: //prueba de vibracion
                                    sp_subStatusFabricacion.setAdapter(adapterVibracion);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                        }
                    });
                }

                String modeloAbreviado;
                modeloAbreviado = modabreviado.get(position);
                String sfolio;
                sfolio = ticket.generarSiguienteNumSerie(idModelo, modeloAbreviado);
                tv_numSerie.setText(sfolio);


            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });



        //Cargamos la fecha del dia actual
        tv_fechaRegistro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Fecharegistro);
        Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        SimpleDateFormat fecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); //14 de enero del 2022
        String Sfecha = fecha.format(date); //convertimos la fecha a string
        tv_fechaRegistro.setText(Sfecha);
        

        //Programacion de botones
        btn_cancelar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCancelarFormulario);
        btn_cancelar.setOnClickListener(v -> finish());

        btn_crear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCrearFormulario);
        btn_crear.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            validarFormulario();
        });

    }

    
    private void validarFormulario() {
        String nombre = et_nombre.getText().toString().trim();
        String comentarios = et_comentarios.getText().toString().trim();
        String cantidadTarjetasString = et_Tarjetas.getText().toString().trim();

        String regexNombre = "^[\\p{L} ]+$";

        int selecfab = sp_statusFabricacion.getSelectedItemPosition();

        if (cantidadTarjetasString.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ingresa la cantidad de tarjetas a crear", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        int cantidadTarjetas = Integer.parseInt(cantidadTarjetasString);

        if (cantidadTarjetas <= 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "La cantidad debe ser mayor que cero", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if(selecfab == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Favor de seleccionar un de estado de fabricación", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        } else if (nombre.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El campo de nombre no puede ir vacío", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        } else if (!nombre.matches(regexNombre)){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El nombre no puede contener caracteres especiales ni números", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        } else if (comentarios.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El campo de comentarios no puede ir vacío", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("creando ticket");
            guardarTarjeta(cantidadTarjetas);
            Intent replyIntent = new Intent();
            replyIntent.putExtra("MI_RESPUESTA", "VALOR DE RESPUESTA");
            setResult(RESULT_OK, replyIntent);
            finish();
        }

    }

    
    private void guardarTarjeta(int cantidadTarjetas) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cantidadTarjetas; i++) { // Corrección en la condición del bucle
            ModeloTarjeta modeloTarjeta = (ModeloTarjeta) sp_modelos.getSelectedItem();
            Integer idModelo = modeloTarjeta.getId();
            String numSerie = tv_numSerie.getText().toString();
            Date fecha = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
            String estado = sp_statusFabricacion.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String subEstado = sp_subStatusFabricacion.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String nombreEnsamblador = et_nombre.getText().toString().trim();
            String comentarios = et_comentarios.getText().toString().trim();

            TarjetaController tarjetaController = new TarjetaController();
            Integer idTarjeta;
            if (estado.equalsIgnoreCase("Entregada")) {
                Tarjeta tarjeta = new Tarjeta(idModelo, numSerie, fecha, fecha, estado, subEstado, Tarjeta.ARCHIVADO);
                idTarjeta = tarjetaController.guardar(tarjeta);
            } else {
                Tarjeta tarjeta = new Tarjeta(idModelo, numSerie, fecha, fecha, estado, subEstado, Tarjeta.FABRICACION);
                idTarjeta = tarjetaController.guardar(tarjeta);
            }

            String textoHistorial =
                    "Subestado: " + subEstado + " \n" +
                            "Comentarios: " + comentarios + "\n";

            Historial historial = new Historial(idTarjeta, fecha, nombreEnsamblador, estado, textoHistorial);
            HistorialController historialController = new HistorialController();
            historialController.guardar(historial);

            Toast.makeText(this, "La tarjeta " + numSerie + " ha sido creado con éxito", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```